# Reading json with require from gulp and close file stream

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm trying to package a chrome extension with gulp-zip. I want to read the manifest.json to get the version number and use it in the zip filename. My code is working however inside the zipped extension, the manifest.json is empty. I'm assuming because the file is open when zip occurs. Any way to read this in and close the stream right away?

```
var zip = require('gulp-zip');
var manifest = require('./src/manifest.json');

gulp.task('build', ['default'], function() {
  return gulp.src('build/**/*')
    .pipe(zip('my-extension-' + manifest.version + '.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Now interestingly enough the below works... what gives?

```
var zip = require('gulp-zip');
var manifest = require('./src/manifest.json');
var manifest2 = require('./src/manifest.json');

gulp.task('build', ['default'], function() {
  return gulp.src('build/**/*')
    .pipe(zip('my-extension-' + manifest.version + '.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem is the scripts running in the ['default'] task were not returning, changed them to return gulp.src(... and we are working now.